# How to pass a parameter in a querystring to multiple pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5, query-string, asp.net-identity

I want to change my site (consists of multiple pages) theme dynamically. I pass a parameter in a querystring as "theme" to all the solution. 
It works just for one page that is redirected with query string (It's theme changes correctly), but other webforms' theme don't change.

so how can I pass a parameter in a querystring to multiple pages?

the below code is an Event that when user click the button, redirect him to other page and change the theme of sit.

```
protected void btn_blue_gray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String bl = "blue";
            Response.Redirect("page1.aspx?theme=" + bl);
        }
```

*if it helps: it's asp.net 4.5 and we used Microsoft.AspNet.Identity package for login User.*

Comment: This question is not clear. *other webforms don't recognize it*? What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

When you navigate to other pages you lose the query string passed in unless you add it to the route/links to other pages yourself.

When you pass a parameter to your page (assuming you login you can do it there) store the theme choice in a bit of state (cookie or session or MemoryCache or something) then just look for this value on each page (or stick it into a MasterPage or baseView with the default being your standard theme value.

something like

```
return Session["theme"] ?? "default";
```

Then every page derived from that MasterPage or View will have access to the theme value (regardless of where you set it).

If you want to allow the user to change the value then set it behind your button click and then navigate or refresh the page and the new theme value will be picked up automatically.

Comment: I replace query string with Session, but after a short time, when I reload the page, It's theme convert to the default theme!!!

Comment: how did you refresh (by navigation) or by reloading the browser ? - Did you write the query string value into the session ?

Comment: by navigate between pages (i think). i have a link of some pages and when click on them, their webforms load. and I don't write query string value into the session.

Comment: if you don't first write it into session then you can't read it out ;)

Comment: I write it first by clicking on a button. at first it works and all page's theme change. but after some minutes, their theme become their default theme!!!

Comment: in "btn_blue_gray_Click" event as I write in my above question

Comment: If you're in your developer IDE then the IDE may reset the session after a few minutes - just part of the clean-up it does, On a web server the theme will remain for as long as you have the same session. Session is by nature designed to time out after a period of inactivity. You should in theory also ask the user to authorize again. So unless you have web clustering or load balancing then your session and your login to the app are probably going to be the same thing and the technique will work - its worked on website for 20+ years.:)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the theme in a global class, which all web forms can access.

public static class Theme
        {
            public static string theme = "";
        }

Comment: how can I use this string (theme) in other webForm code?

Comment: just use it as Theme.theme = "whatever value you want"